# MySQL - How to measure the amount of space used by certain rows?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project management program, built on a LAMP stack.  I have tentatively chosen not to provide each one of my clients with their own database, but rather to combine all business' data into one large database.

The first column in all database tables is business_id.  This row indicates which business a certain piece of data belongs to, which keeps us from exposing Business 1's data to Business 2.

But as I try to iron out the billing kinks, it would be very useful to be able to run a cron job once a month to determine how much database space each business is using.  So here's my question: Is there a way to get MySQL to return the number of bytes used by all rows WHERE business_id = 'x'?

Comment: not really, but you can figure it out yourself by manually tallying the field types + basic sizes of those fields yourself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use one table per business, then you could see the file size of the table in the file system.

Comment: there is a `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, but that'll only give you ... the avarage.

Comment: It seems that any design that would require you to put a business id field in each table of the database is a bad one.  If you have this particular requirement (for billing or something like that), then I would suggest using a database per client, or at the very minimum separate tables per client.

Comment: @wroniasty Is providing some useful information here in that average row length * number of rows IS the table size. However, you would not be able to use this for tables where businesses are mixed.

Comment: @mikeBrant, it is called multi-tenancy. it rocks. not every table would require the biz id, just the top level one(s) if you know how to do a join it is safe

Comment: @DrewPierce I fully agree for most normal purposes, but if he has this requirement to be able to separately meter database size for diferent tenants, it would become trivial to to do this with separate schemas or tables.  As you mention, even if you don't choose to separate the schemas/tables there is no reason to add a business id to every table, as you would be able to derive business association on most tables via join withe appropriate tables where this data is kept.

Comment: @MikeBrant, i also shudder at the provisioning nightmare and code changes needed for hundreds of thousands of tables ... a new group for each client. clearly quickbooks-online or the like would never do this. i would keep it simple, go with the average rowsize concept and do the math. of course if the op can't safely write multi-tenant  code then yikes. it is not likely that client A is gonna go with low varchar storage and client B is going with huge varchar storage, but what do i know

Comment: @DrewPierce Good thoughts. For most field data types the range of values in the field (and accordingly the size of the values) may not be drastic enough from one client to the next such that average row size * rows for the client would not be a good proxy for overall data usage.  If however you had large text or blob fields that stored widely variable data size, that might not be appropriate.  Of course for these cases, if you have a string value, you can directly calculate the sizes of such fields using `BIT_LENGTH()`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments. Reading through the whole discussion is _very_ helpful as we decide which way to move forward (multi-tenant, separate databases per customer, or a combination of both).

Answer (score 2):

Since you will probably only be billing for the information the customer is explicitly paying you to store, just sum up the lengths of the fields they explicitly give you. (Omit internal fields like `business_id`, `service_level_id`, `permissions`, or whatever.) Then, refer to the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) and calculate.

So, where B is the number of bytes required for all numeric fields, and there are 3 text fields txtA, txtB, and txtC, for instance:

```
select
    business_id,
    count(*) * B +
        sum(length(txtA) + length(txtB) + length(txtC)) as bytes
from table
where business_id={id};
```

But, once you've got a reasonable amount of data in your system, I suspect that query is going to be pretty long-running. It might be simpler to just tell your clients you'll be billing them on their "approximate" data storage. Use the `average_row_length * count(*)` of their rows and trim a little off to account for your overhead.

Comment: took you an hr to just copy my answer ?

Comment: @DrewPierce A) I only saw your answer about 1/2 hour ago, and I was out to lunch. B) Your answer is wrong. Mine isn't.

Comment: you are summing on length just like i am. show a sqlfiddle so we can critique it too. and then in the end u say dont use it but avg_row

Comment: @DrewPierce ... nope. Not "just" summing up length. Maybe read the answer before commenting on it?

Comment: i did read the answer. the client has storage for other fields. provide a sqlfiddle. i know it takes effort

Comment: @DrewPierce I sincerely have no idea what your objection is ... Nor am I convinced you read my answer.

Comment: so they have to hand calculate the int sizes, it does not take into account the extra byte for varchar, it wont work on multi-byte char sets, and you say dont use it but use avg_row

Comment: @DrewPierce Sure. Pretty distinctly not your answer in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT
  table_schema, count(*) TABLES,
  concat(round(sum(table_rows)/1000000,2),'M')
  rows,concat(round(sum(data_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G')
  DATA,concat(round(sum(index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G')
  idx,concat(round(sum(data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G')
  total_size,round(sum(index_length)/sum(data_length),2) idxfrac
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES group by table_schema;
```